# Error with outputing task title in simple_calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have database like this

```
create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "title"
t.text "content"
t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
t.integer "user_id"
t.datetime "start_time"
```

end

And i have declared tasks in index as meetings, like this:

```
@tasks = Task.all
```

And then i tried to output them like:

```
    <%= month_calendar attribute: :start_time, events: @tasks do |date, tasks| %>
  <%= date %>
  <% tasks.each do |task| %>
    <div>
      <%= task.title %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And all i got is an:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUvfs.png)

Answer (score 0):

it's a syntax problem. You closed arguments list by braces, `events: ...` are floating in space

```
<%= month_calendar attribute: :start_time, events: @meetings do |date, meetings| %>
```

Comment: now I get "NoMethodError in Tasks#show
Showing C:/projekti/school-from-home/app/views/simple_calendar/_simple_calendar.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #1):
1
2
3
4
5
6
              
<%= month_calendar attribute: :start_time, events: @tasks do |date, tasks| %>
  <%= date %>
  <% tasks.each do |task| %>
    <div>
      <%= task.title %>
    </div>

Trace of template inclusion: #<ActionView::Template app/views/layouts/application.html.erb locals=[]>

Rails.root: C:/projekti/school-from-home"

Comment: You should be happy with that: new error means that you're stepping forward ;)
I cannot help without seeing the whole controller view and model code

Answer (score 0):

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]
```

def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

def show
    @meetings = Task.all
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

end

def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

def create
    @task = Task.create(task_params)
    @task.user = current_user

```
if @task.save
  redirect_to @task
else
  render :new
end
```

end

def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

```
if @task.update(task_params)
  redirect_to @task
else
  render :edit
end
```

end

def destroy 
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

```
@task.destroy
redirect_to :action  => :index
```

end

private

def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :content, :start_time)
  end
end

That is my controller model